# Is there an easy way to transfer Firefox extensions and profiles from one OS to another on the same computer?

Tags: windows-vista, firefox, browser-addons, ubuntu-netbook-remix, transfer

I'm assuming that most, if not all, the extensions and changes to the userchrome.css will work on Ubuntu Netbook, so I'm looking for a simple way to transfer them all from my primary Vista OS to my Ubuntu Netbook OS, on the same machine. It also has to be free. I am the most current stable build of Firefox 3.6.5 on both systems.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an addon like [Siphon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11778/) to sync addon. For profiles & bookmarks, you can use [Weave](http://mozillalabs.com/weave/)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just manually copy the profile directory over to the new OS - I've done this successfully from Windows to OS X.  See http://support.mozilla.com/en-us/kb/profiles#Where_is_my_profile_stored_ to find the location of your profile, then just copy the whole directory over.

Comment: i've had apparent success with this, but recently i've realized my old profile (copied from WinXP to Ubuntu) didn't seem to keep the disk cache in the same place -- i'm not sure it was keeping a disk cache at all.  ended up creating a new profile with fresh settings since i couldn't track down the trouble.  i think a profile sync addon will be more successful than a straight-up file copy.

Answer (score 0):

[MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/) is the one and only program you need to use. I get transfered a lot between several offices and PCs and work like a charm.